# Extract training data with correspond to a reference image

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

While extracting the pixel values from a given image, the following technique works, with given geometries (feature collection `fc`).

```
var training = image.sampleRegions({
  collection: fc,
  properties: ['land cover'],
  scale: 100});
```

However, my requirement is that, I want to extract pixel values, using a corresponding image, instead of `fc`

How can I achieve it?

I'm dealing with two classes (0 and 1) for classification.

`image` is a multi-channel image.

I need to extract all pixel values with correspond to reference image's `0` pixels as `0` feature value and `1` as feature value `1`.

The reference image has 4 values, `[0,1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ee.Image.sample` instead of `ee.Image.sampleRegions`. `sample` will sample each pixel in the image (or at a chosen scale) rather than using any geometry input.

```
var training = image.sample({
  region: areaOfInterest,  // omit to use the image's footprint
});
```

In order to control the sampling area pixel-wise, mask your image before sampling it. In order to get the reference values, add its band.

```
var training = image
    .updateMask(ref.le(1))
    .addBands(ref.rename(['reference']))
    .sample({ ...
```

Comment: @mk1 I added a description of how to do that. Thanks for editing your question to clarify it!

Comment: @mk1 The features will have properties named after the bands of the image. One of them will be 'reference' (since I wrote that name in `addBands`) with the `0` and `1` values, and the others will be whatever band names your `image` has.

Comment: @mk1 Oops, I misread the docs. You need to either use whatever band name the reference image actually has (`print(ref.bandNames())` to find out) or don't specify the second argument in which case you'll get whatever its band name already is as your output property name, or use `rename()` to set the band name.

Comment: `Layer 3: Layer error: Classifier.train: InputProperties must be specified. `during `.train(...`

Comment: .sample with masked image yielded 0 samples even with large numPixels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112361/discussion-between-kevin-reid-and-mk1).